# Izpack Maven plugin Invalid base directory on Eclipse Maven project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, izpack

When I'm going to Maven-install my project with pom

```
 <build>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/izpack</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/izpack</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Configure the compiler to use Java 1.5 -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Have project dependencies be picked up by izPack when its compiler runs -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
                <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0-rc4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
                        <artifactId>izpack-panel</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0.0-rc4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <!-- mvn help:describe -DgroupId=org.codehaus.izpack -DartifactId=izpack-maven-plugin -Dversion=5.0.0-beta11 -Ddetail -->
                <configuration>
                    <installFile>${staging.dir}/install.xml</installFile>
                    <attach>false</attach>
                    <kind>standard</kind>
                    <descriptorEncoding>UTF-8</descriptorEncoding>
                    <izpackBasedir>${staging.dir}</izpackBasedir>
                    <customPanelDirectory>${staging.dir}</customPanelDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>standard-installer</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>izpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Do not deploy any of the installer artifacts. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
   <properties>
    <staging.dir>${project.build.directory}/staging</staging.dir>
  </properties>
```

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.izpack:izpack-maven-plugin:5.0.0-rc4:izpack (standard-installer) on project Izpack-Installer: Failure during compilation process: Invalid base directory: workspace/myproject/target/staging

The above error is making my whole day waste... please post working pom of izpack Maven plugin which support console installation in Linux.

**Note:** I placed my install.xml in src/main/izpack/install.xml as well as src/main/resources/install.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after end of the day got answer...:)

```
<build>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Configure the compiler to use Java 1.7 -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Have project dependencies be picked up by izPack when its compiler runs -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
                <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0-rc4</version>
                 <configuration>

        <installerFile>${basedir}/target</installerFile>
        <izpackBasedir>${staging.dir}</izpackBasedir>
        <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
              <artifactId>izpack-standalone-compiler</artifactId>
              <version>4.3.5</version>
            </dependency>
                </dependencies>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>izpack</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>izpack</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Do not deploy any of the installer artifacts. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
   <properties>
    <staging.dir>${project.build.directory}/staging</staging.dir>
  </properties>
```

"staging" directory in target folder is created manually....:)

Comment: "manually"? What happen in case you run something like mvn clean izpack:izpack?